# AngularJS Service function calling another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a AngularJS application that has a service module.
I have simplyfied what i want to do in the code below.
I want one service function to get a value from another function in the same service.

```
service.factory(....)
return {
    //test function want to get the value from "info" in test2.
    test: function () {
        var text = this.test2;
        return text;
    },
    test2: function () {
        var info = "Hello World";
        return info;
    }
```

When i call "test" function it returns the entire function:

```
function () {
        var info = "Hello World";
        return info;
    }
```

and not the "Hello World".
Can someone explain why its not returning the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *call* `test2`.

```
test: function () {
    var text = this.test2();  // <-- here
    return text;
},
```

Comment: Thank you. Abit annoying to miss it :(